# UIImageView overflowing custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6, constraints

I have a custom table view cell with a UIImage on the left, and two labels on the right one on-top of the other. I originally had only the image and one label, and the image was fitting perfectly inside the cell, but after I added the second label, the table view cell is smaller and doesn't contain the full image(even though the image is still the same size as it was), and doesn't contain the second label. So for some reason after I added the second label the custom tableview cell shrunk in heigh and won't contain them. I have messed with constraints for hours and can't seem to find the right ones. And yes, the image is aspect fit.

Let me know your thoughts, this might be a simple fix, I just simply can't find that fix. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some code or screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on your UIImageView, ensure that it has Mode set to "Scale To Fill" In the attributes inspector. It can be done programatically like this if you want:

```
newImgThumb.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Also, make sure that your constraints are not conflicting and are properly arranged. If this doesn't work post some screenshots and I will take another crack.

Comment: Thank you for comment but I ended up taking away the second label because I wanted to move it to a different screen. Thank you for your answer nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Set mode of image view Aspect Fill, and select Clip Subview in XIB/Storyboard.

Hopefully it works. Thanks